# xerces issue in 64 bit HPUX machine

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

Getting this error during compilation of tuxedo domain. It is for 64 bit HP-UX machine.

**expected an identifier
  typedef RefArrayVectorOf  StringList;**

/home/xerces-c-3.0.0-ia64_64-hpux-acc-6/xerces-c-3.0.0-ia64_64-hpux-acc-6/include/xercesc/framework/psvi/XSConstants.hpp

I have provided the correct include paths in Makefile.
Unable to figure out why XMLCh is not identified.

Including this didnt work in XSconstants.hpp

## include

Comment: I included this in XSConstants.hpp

Comment: #include <xercesc/util/Xerces_autoconf_config.hpp>